# AppEngine + Objectify - Can I turn a Key<Object> back into Object?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm doing a simple asynchronous put operation with Objectify:

```
ofy().async().put(object);
```

This returns Result< Key< ObjectEntity>>, and I can call

```
Result<Key<ObjectEntity>> result = ofy().async().put(object);
```

And then I can call .get() on that to block until I get the result:

```
Key<ObjectEntity> objectKey = result.get();
```

But what can I do with this objectKey in order to get my object entity back? I basically want to be able to send this as an object back to GWT.

Comment: wanted to clarify, you want to send the key back to ure webapp? but just to let you know, you really shouldn't have to hold on to the key object to be able to retrieve the object...u would insert an object with some id into the datastore and then when you wanted to retrieve your object, you would create a new key: new new Key<Car>(Entity.class,entityId)

Comment: Why do you need to get your object 'back'? You still have it in `object`, which you passed to the original put operation.

Comment: Nadir, I put an object in the data store, and all I can get out is the key of the object. I want the actual object. If I do a non-async get, that's what I get back.

Comment: Nick, the reason I want the updated object to return it is because I'm converting my app from jdo and that's the way my current app worka. Also, I believe there were other instances that I needed to be able to convert from a key to the original object. It would make my life a lot simpler if it were possible without having to do a call on each significant record of the key in order to reconstruct the object. Its early, but I believe I was having the same issue with asynchronous gets, which would be happening when I don't have access to the object that I put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your object back:

```
Result<Foo> fooResult = ofy.async().get(Foo.class, "foo1-id");
Foo foo = fooResult.get();
```

I tried my hands with Objectify a little so I'm definitely not an expert but you might want to make sure that if you're putting an object into the datastore with an async put call, that you block until it has been inserted into the datastore before calling. If you're going to end up needing to retrieve an entity immediately after inserting it, you're defeating the purpose of using async.put().

Also you probably know this but the Objectify folks have done a decent job of putting together their [API Javadoc](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html) for reference.